# convert dataframe to libsvm format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataframe resulting from a sql query

```
df1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from table_test")
```

I need to convert this dataframe to libsvm format so that it can be provided as an input for

```
pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
```

I tried to do the following. However, this resulted in the following error as I'm using spark 1.5.2

```
df1.write.format("libsvm").save("data/foo")
Failed to load class for data source: libsvm
```

I wanted to use MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile instead. I'm behind a firewall and can't directly pip install it. So I downloaded the file, scp-ed it and then manually installed it. Everything seemed to work fine but I still get the following error

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
No module named org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils
```

Question 1: Is my above approach to convert dataframe to libsvm format in the right direction.
Question 2: If "yes" to question 1, how to get MLUtils working. If "no", what is the best way to convert dataframe to libsvm format

Comment: can you provide an example of a df1 row? Because as you can see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=saveaslib#pyspark.mllib.util.MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/python/pyspark.mllib.util.MLUtils-class.html), saveAsLibSVMFile needs a RDD of LabeledPoint, so before you convert dataframe to libsvm you have to take into consideration the meaning of your data in df1.

Comment: instead of `import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils`, have you tried `from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils` ?

Comment: from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would act like that (it's just an example with an arbitrary dataframe, I don't know how your df1 is done, focus is on data transformations):

This is my way to convert dataframe to libsvm format:

```
# ... your previous imports

from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

# A DATAFRAME
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  3|  6|  
|  4|  5| 20|
|  7|  8|  8|
+---+---+---+

# FROM DATAFRAME TO RDD
>>> c = df.rdd # this command will convert your dataframe in a RDD
>>> print (c.take(3))
[Row(_1=1, _2=3, _3=6), Row(_1=4, _2=5, _3=20), Row(_1=7, _2=8, _3=8)]

# FROM RDD OF TUPLE TO A RDD OF LABELEDPOINT
>>> d = c.map(lambda line: LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1:]])) # arbitrary mapping, it's just an example
>>> print (d.take(3))
[LabeledPoint(1.0, [3.0,6.0]), LabeledPoint(4.0, [5.0,20.0]), LabeledPoint(7.0, [8.0,8.0])]

# SAVE AS LIBSVM
>>> MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile(d, "/your/Path/nameFolder/")
```

What you will see on the "/your/Path/nameFolder/part-0000*" files is:

1.0 1:3.0 2:6.0

4.0 1:5.0 2:20.0

7.0 1:8.0 2:8.0

See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-data-types.html#labeled-point) for LabeledPoint docs

Comment: What if DataFrame contains `None`?

Comment: I am currently also experimenting with the LibSVM format as standardized format for exchanging label/feature data sets between Python and Java in a Spark project. However, I am a bit confused by the multiple files that are created as per @titiro89's solution. 

Why is the data split across multiple files and how can I save it to a single text file? Or, alternatively, how can I read these multiple 'part-0000*' files? AFAICS, the method `loadLibSVMFile()` in Spark's MLUtils.util requires a single file, which is strange; `saveAsLibSVMFile()` in the same util file will produce  multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this for it to work

```
D.map(lambda line: LabeledPoint(line[0],[line[1],line[2]]))
```

Comment: So far this is a comment. Please explain why this works for you and why the accepted answer doesn't work. Please make this an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert sparse vectors to a 'sparse' libsvm which is more efficient, try this:

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors as MLLibVectors
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, Vectors.sparse(5, [(1, 1.0), (3, 7.0)])),
    (1, Vectors.sparse(5, [(1, 1.0), (3, 7.0)])),
    (1, Vectors.sparse(5, [(1, 1.0), (3, 7.0)]))
], ["label", "features"])
df.show()

# +-----+-------------------+
# |label|           features|
# +-----+-------------------+
# |    0|(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
# |    1|(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
# |    1|(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
# +-----+-------------------+

MLUtils.saveAsLibSVMFile(df.rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x.label, MLLibVectors.fromML(x.features))), './libsvm')
```