# Save pysaprk dataframe in libsvm format to s3

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I have a pyspark data frame with two columns - `features` and `label`.

`features` is a sparse vector I have created after multiple transformations and finally used  `vectorassembler`. I want to write this dataframe to s3 in libsvm format but I am struggling to get any leads on how to do that.

Edit 1:
Looking for a solution without converting the dataframe to RDD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert dataframe to libsvm format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920111/convert-dataframe-to-libsvm-format)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I am familiar with this way but I am looking for a way without moving from dataframe to RDD. Editing my question.

Comment: @molbdnilo Wasn't aware. Thank you for pointing it out.